# JSON Firebase URL to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase

I need to get as array a firebase link. I have the following link https://.firebaseio.com/users.json which is going to retrieve the following json file:

```
{
    "-KOIbPUxKWKMaIOuX1cR": {
        "email": "fillocj.rc@gmail.co",
        "lastName": "Alberto",
        "password": "password",
        "userName": "Rodolfo"
    },
    "-KOOF5S3kDnvsT9nVx85": {
        "email": "test@test2.com",
        "lastName": "TEST",
        "password": "password",
        "userName": "TEST"
    }
}
```

and I am using the following function in javascript to get make a conversion:

```
var o = 'https://<myInstance>.firebaseio.com/users.json';
var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function (k) { return o[k] });
console.log(arr)
```

But the result if this function is the following:

```
Array[53]

0:"h"
1:"t"
2:"t"
3:"p"
4:"s"
5:":"
6:"/"
7:"/"
8:"a"
9:"g"
10:"u"
11:"l"
12:"a"
13:"r"
14:"f"
15:"i"
16:"r"
17:"e"
18:"d"
```

And of course this is not what I need, I need to retrieve all emails or all users or all id numbers. Is there any way to retrieve that? Or can somebody help me out with a piece of code which can help me with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery map function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to map objects.

```
$.map(source, function(item, i){
    return source.email; //return what you want
});
```

If you just want to retrieve the json content from the url you need to make an AJAX request. A simple way of doing this is using [getJSON function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
    $.getJSON("https://<myInstance>.firebaseio.com/users.json", function(result){
        // here you get the JSON content
    });
```

Take a look at this snippet:

```js
window.users = {
    "-KOIbPUxKWKMaIOuX1cR": {
        "email": "fillocj.rc@gmail.co",
        "lastName": "Alberto",
        "password": "password",
        "userName": "Rodolfo"
    },
    "-KOOF5S3kDnvsT9nVx85": {
        "email": "test@test2.com",
        "lastName": "TEST",
        "password": "password",
        "userName": "TEST"
    }
};



function getEmails(users){
  return $.map(users, function(item, i){
   return item.email;
  });
};

function getSampleObject(users){
  return $.map(users, function(item, i){
      return {
        email: item.email,
        username: item.userName
      };
    });
};

$(window).ready(function(){
  var emails, users;
  
  emails = getEmails(window.users);
  users = getSampleObject(window.users);  
  
  $('#output_1').text(JSON.stringify(emails));
  $('#output_2').text(JSON.stringify(users));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Retrieves email</h2>
<code id="output_1"></code>
<hr />
<h2>Retrieves object</h2>
<code id="output_2"></code>
```

Comment: This is amazing! But how can I code it from AJAX request?. Please, the example is great! Please!! I am reading the documentation but it'd work a thousand times better with the ajax request! Please, please!

Comment: When you make a AJAX you get the result in a callback function because it is asynchronous. So you will pass a function that expect the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = 'https://<myInstance>.firebaseio.com/users.json';
var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function (k) { return o[k] });
console.log(arr)
```

As I see your var `o` is equal to the url (string) you need firstable make the request... using ajax or whatever you want if you see the array contains every word of the url...

Comment: No no I don't need to retrieve the every word of the  `var o`, what I need to do is to retrieve all email variables from the url. I am so sorry maybe I did not explain well my question.

Comment: yeah i know but i'm saying that what's in your code, you're returning the url because you're not making an ajax request first